# WHERE equals condition returns mapped Unicode (fullwidth) results

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, unicode, sql-server-2014, collation

We are querying a SQL Server database for names that are stored in a `nvarchar` column. In this table, we have two values that are conflicting with each other. `Ｗｏｒｄ` and `Word`. The first one is made out of full width Latin letters.

When we try to select the ASCII name, the Unicode version also returns. This causes conflicts as the query should only be able to return one row. Below is a query which can be used to reproduce the results:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN N'Ｗｏｒｄ' = N'Word' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END;
```

This query returns `1`, while we expect it to return `0`. It seems that SQL Server maps Unicode based versions of each letter to their ASCII variant.

Is there a way to disable this mapping between the ASCII and Unicode characters? While still being able to ignore the capitalization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When we try to select the ASCII name, the Unicode version also returns.

This statement is a bit of a misunderstanding of how encodings work. ASCII is an 8-bit encoding and a character set. It is values 0 - 127 and is common across most code pages and Unicode. However, it really only applies to `VARCHAR` data. When using `NVARCHAR`, then all characters are Unicode, even if those characters are found in other character sets. So here, you are only getting Unicode characters returned since `NVARCHAR` only holds Unicode characters (encoded as UTF-16 Little Endian). It just so happens that the ASCII character set was duplicated as a subset of Unicode.

Meaning, what you are really saying here is that you want the regular Latin characters only, not the fullwidth version.

> It seems that SQL Server maps Unicode based versions of each letter to their ASCII variant.

Yes and no. Windows and SQL Server *can* map Unicode characters to similar looking characters within an 8-bit code page, but that only happens when converting a Unicode string to an 8-bit code page (or from one code page to another). That is not happening here. Here, again, you are only dealing with Unicode. It just so happens that both regular and fullwidth forms of the US English alphabet are considered equal when the Collation is Width *In*sensitive. And based on your question and the test case (two separate things since a column's Collation is used when querying a column, but the DB's default Collation is used when dealing only with string literals and/or variables), it is clear that the Collations you are using (which could both be the same Collation) are Width *In*sensitive.

To fix this, please do not use a binary Collation. Using a binary Collation is the unfortunately commonly-accepted go-to answer to fix queries when people get more matches than they were expecting. And sometimes it is the correct answer, but more often than not, such as with this question, it isn't.

You simply need to add "width sensitivity" to the Collation that you are using. You can find the column's Collation with the following query, just fill in the correct table name and column name:

```
SELECT col.[collation_name]
FROM   sys.columns col
WHERE  col.[object_id] = OBJECT_ID(N'<schema_name>.<table_name>')
AND    col.[name] = N'<column_name>';
```

If the Collation is a Windows Collation (i.e. the name does *not* start with `SQL_`) then you might just be able to add `_WS` to the end of the Collation name. For example:

`Latin1_General_100_CS_AS` --> `Latin1_General_100_CS_AS_WS`

If the Collation is a SQL Server Collation (i.e. name *does* start with `SQL_`), then none of those allow for width sensitivity and you should choose an equivalent Windows Collation. If the Collation is `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_*`, then try the same thing start with `Latin1_General_100_`.

```
-- current Collation (no width sensitivity)
SELECT CASE WHEN N'Ｗｏｒｄ' = N'Word' COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CI_AS THEN 1
            ELSE 0 END;
-- 1


-- add width sensitivity
SELECT CASE WHEN N'Ｗｏｒｄ' = N'Word' COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CI_AS_WS THEN 1
            ELSE 0 END;
-- 0


-- confirm case INsensitivity
SELECT CASE WHEN N'WORD' = N'Word' COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CI_AS_WS THEN 1
            ELSE 0 END;
-- 1
```

For more details on why you should first attempt to get the correct sensitivity before using a binary Collation, please see the following post of mine:

[No, Binary Collations are not Case-Sensitive](https://sqlquantumleap.com/2017/07/13/no-binary-collations-are-not-case-sensitive/)

Comment: Great answer! Is there any risk to changing a columns collation from a sql collation to a windows collation? Can data be lost or warped?

Comment: @bladefist Thanks! And, the "type" of Collation isn't the issue. If you are talking about an `NVARCHAR` / `NCHAR` / `NTEXT` column, then there can't be any data loss as Unicode is a single character set inclusive of all characters. If you are talking about `VARCHAR` / `CHAR` / `TEXT`, then the difference is only if you are changing code pages, in which case there is potential for data loss if the new code page doesn't contain all characters currently in the data. But that risk exists going from any Collation to any other, regardless of type or version, etc.

Comment: @bladefist Also, that is a good question, but really should be posted as a separate question and not just in a comment. Please post (if it hasn't been asked before) and paste a link to it here and I will answer it.  I also have a 2 part blog series on pretty much that topic, starting with: [Which Collation is Used to Convert NVARCHAR to VARCHAR in a WHERE Condition? (Part A of 2: “Duck”)](https://sqlquantumleap.wordpress.com/2017/12/08/which-collation-is-used-to-convert-nvarchar-to-varchar-in-a-where-condition-part-a-of-2-duck/).

Answer (score 2):

You need to use COLLATION.

Follow my examples and find out which collation is suitable for you

**This collation returns 1**

```
SELECT CASE WHEN N'Ｗｏｒｄ' COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS = N'Word' COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

**This collation returns 0**

```
SELECT CASE WHEN N'Ｗｏｒｄ' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_Cp437_BIN = N'Word' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_Cp437_BIN THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

The collation specifier, tells SQL Server how to compare characters.

[Find more detail here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/collations/collation-and-unicode-support)

[List of collations](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180175(v=sql.105).aspx)

Because you may have more variety in your data, I can't tell what collation is best for you.

Comment: Thanks! The second collation `SQL_Latin1_General_Cp437_BIN`. Works in the case of Unicode and ASCII. But it will also return 0 on `word == WORD`. Is there another one that doesn't match on Unicode but still matches different capitalizations?

Comment: You can find more information in the links I just added to my answer